# Is it possible that a new transistor is not good even if a current runs through it?

Tags: transistors, repair

I just got an NTE121 replacement transistor for an old 2N2148 that was in a guitar amp.  It was the only part I replaced and now I have no sound coming from the speaker.  I checked every component on the board with a multimeter and did not find any dead spots, including the new transistor.  Is it possible that a new transistor could be dead out of the box?  I have really only ever dealt with capacitors before.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it outside the amp first?

Comment: Do you mean for continuity?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  But it's more likely that either the new transistor is not a direct replacement (pinout might be different, etc) or that some other failure in the amp which lead to the original transistor failure, is still there causing problems.

Comment: Did you check power supply voltages are within spec? Including its ripple?

Comment: Ah.  With a little more tinkering (including the "tap the transistor on the head" test) I found that a silicon-based transistor, in the chain ahead of the one I replaced, has gone bad also.  The amp flared up into life with a few taps on that one and quickly faded out again so I think I found that problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a bad soldering/connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another transistor in the signal chain was causing the loss of signal..